# Zonal statistics multiple band raster

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, zonal-statistics, multi-band

I have a raster which is a yearly time series, it is created with 30 raster. It is saved then as a raster with multiple bands.

I am trying to calculate the zonal statistics of all the bands at once. Imagine this like a "sandwich" (raster layers) and I want the mean and std of all the bands exactly where my finger press (zonal in vector file).

I used this analogy because, it is hard sometimes to express how the zonal statistics should be calculated for all the bands.

I have tried with ArcGIS, but I have the impression that the results are wrong. How can I do this either in QGIS or ArcGIS

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop you wish to ask about in this particular question. That way you will be able to describe precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: What versions do you have available? Especially for QGIS, there are quite some differences between version 2 and 3. In any case, I think you need to either script it with Python or run `Zonal Statistics` as batch (one run for each band) and then re-combine the results manually.